# Download Data from firebase in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to build a contactScreen for my flutter app. Therefor I have to download an array from Firebase. I am just able to download directly into a listView in flutter and get stuck while coding. Heres my code:

```
var currentUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
var contacts;
getUserData() async {
var userData = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('users')
    .where('uid', isEqualTo: currentUser)
    .get();
contacts = userData['contacs']; //heres the error 
}
```

At first I want to initialize the currentUser's UID and then get the currentUser's contacts array from firebase. Therefor I build the getUserData() method to download the User and then initialize his contacts array.

The last step doesn't work in Flutter, I can't access the contacts array. Is the way I want to get the data correct?

Comment: can you share the error

Comment: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Future<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>'.
Try defining the operator '[]'.

Comment: I think I forgot to call a method or something else...

Answer (score 0):

You're at the very least missing an `await` before the `get()` call:

```
var userData = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection('users')
  .where('uid', isEqualTo: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
  .get();
```

Without `await` your `userData` is of type `Future<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>` as you get in the error message. By using `await`, its type will become `QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>`.

Comment: Hi, so i edited my post above. In Flutter we can't access the data with the init method and otherwise we can't start the getData() method. So I changed the code as shown in the post above. Do you think that should work? The emulator just shows me 'Instance of '_JsonQuerrySnapshot'... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you need to call await or use FutureBuilder
like this

```
FutureBuilder(
      future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('users')
          .where('uid', isEqualTo: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
          .get(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {

          return Column(
        children: [Text(snapshot.data['name'])], //error here
      );
        }
        return Loading();
      },
    )
```